# Боксерские перчатки или рукавицы?

Tags: терминология

Один из популярных риторических вопросов: "Почему боксерские перчатки, если они варежки?" А действительно, почему? Уж правильнее было бы назвать рукавицами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В английском, откуда заимствовали наименование, понятия рукавица нет, поэтому и в русском варианте тоже перчатки.